# SQL to select data in multiple row based on column

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write a Oracle sql query which will fetch data in below order:

```html
NAME    Phone1  Phone2
JOHN    1123     321
RIK 11  Null
KATE    Null    21
```

Output:

```html
NAME    PHONE
JOHN    1123
JOHN    321
RIK 11
KATE    21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using UNION ALL

```
select name, phone1 as phone from tablenmae
union all
select name, phone2  from tablenmae
```

OR You can try using UNPVOT

```
select *
  from tablenmae
unpivot
(
    phone
    for val in (phone1, phone2)
)
```

Comment: [Doesn't work just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5df506d9da02743090bb266fccb53cab).

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `UNION ALL` here:

```
SELECT NAME, Phone1 AS PHONE FROM yourTable WHERE Phone1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT NAME, Phone2 FROM yourTable WHERE Phone2 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY NAME, PHONE;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

select name,phone1 from table1 where phone1 is not null
union
select name,phone2 from table1 where phone2 is not null